# MYSQL select and limit by quantity of 'group by'

Tags: php, mysql, limit

My query is as follows:

```
            $query = "SELECT report,";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT analyst) AS analysts, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT region) AS regions, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country) AS countries, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT topic) AS topics, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT date) AS dates, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT link) AS links, ";
            $query.=    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT province) AS provinces ";
            $query.=    "FROM reports GROUP BY report ORDER BY dates DESC ";
```

I would like for MySQL to GROUP BY report, and also to limit that number (of reports) to 10. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `LIMIT 10` to the end of your query.

Comment: Wow. That command does not work the way I expected it to there, I thought it would return 10 records... How would do you that then?